# fstream file opening start piont

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I am opening file with full path

```
fin.open(C:/Users/User/Desktop/MyFiles/File/file.txt);
```

and without

```
 fin.open(../File/file.txt);
```

And both works fine :
Does that mean that `C:/Users/User/Desktop/MyFiles` is useless and in both ways fstream starts opening file from `/File/` folder ??:
And if it is right how can I force it to start from `C:/..`?.(because sometimes it could not open with full path).

Comment: You need to understand the concept of the process *current working directory* and the effect it has on relative paths.  Having said that, if both calls work, then they operate in exactly the same way.

Comment: And how I understand I can set directory to `C:/..` with SetCurrentDirectory() and it will start opening file from `C:/..`?

Comment: You can practise in the command prompt.  Cd somewhere and do `dir \windows` or `dir ..`.  It's the same thing; the command prompt has a current working directory and you can address files/directories using either an absolute or relative path.